# What did the entity in Paranormal Activity write on the ouija board?

Tags: paranormal-activity

At a certain point in the movie Paranormal Activity, the entity writes a message out on a Ouija board.  However, I was unable to make out what it said, if anything.  It seems this was the only time when the entity tried to convey a message to the family.  What did the entity write out?  Was it an actual message or was it just gibberish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the answer is that it is never clearly explained in the movie (and perhaps in the sequels).

Below comment from @Walt explains it -

> They show the board up-close and there are some vague scorch marks on
>   it, but nothing readable. He just comes to the conclusion that it
>   spell out 'Diane' (which leads him to the website about the possessed
>   girl), but we don't know if he's right. We just assume it.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, the scorch marks had "666", and demonic images of some animal on the left bottom corner.

Comment: Could you provide some screenshots or something to back this up?

Answer (score -1):

I always thought (I don't know why, but I think it sounds cool) that it says "Nadie" which in my language (Spanish) means "nobody"